# When do normal distributions not occur?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that in many cases one can assume a normal distributed probability density. But what the situations when the distribution in non-normal. Some examples would be nice.

**For example**, suppose there is a voting about when it should be legal to buy alcohol. Then one would not see a normal distribution with peak at (say) 18 years old. Rather one sees some peeks at too young and some at a little to old and so on. But if one would see a normal distribution here (say around 18 years old), what would that tell you?

Comment: you should check out the Central Limit Theorem first

Answer (score 1):

Many cases of what kind? If you are taking a mean of a large sample drawn from independent identical distributions, then under certain conditions given by the Central limit theorem the distribution of the result will tend towards a normal distribution when the sample size tends to infinity. But in other cases, whatever you're talking about can have all kinds of distributions. For example, the number of failures of a machine within each time period is a discrete distribution that only takes non-negative values, and is certainly not a normal distribution. It often can be modeled by a Poisson distribution.

As for the question you added later, seeing a so-called normal distribution is a difficult problem. There are a number of [Normality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_tests), but it still cannot really prove anything; remember that statistics can be misleading once in a while even if you are unbiased! If however you have some hypothesis about why some distribution should be normal, then these statistics can give some supporting evidence towards that claim.

Answer (score 0):

The central limit theorem talks about instances where things are added together, roughly speaking.

But there might be instances where you have things multiplied together instead, giving you a lognormal distribution. [Gibrat's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibrat%27s_law) is one famous example.